# Reducing the size of executable from py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

Are there some practices to minimize the size of .exe file created by py2exe when creating executable of python script? My first impression upon using py2exe is, it creates relatively large size file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to compress, which you can enable in the config file, but it will always be relatively large (~megabytes) because python interpreter must also be bundled in with the source code.

Comment: Is there a tradeoff when compressing? Any reason not to compress?

Comment: Yes - the tradeoff is that it will be slower to execute, because things must be uncompressed at beginning of runtime.