# How to turn python to exe with only needed parts of library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, auto-py-to-exe

I made a simple script, turned it into an exe but the final output using auto py to exe with one directory mode was 170 mb, with one file mode it was 64 mb. Thats insane, anyway I can only copy the parts of libraries that my script needs?

EDIT: My script is simple, [this is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543616/this-somehow-freezes-my-whole-program-and-im-not-sure-why) The libraries are tkinter, keyboard, pyautogui, pywinauto and time.

Comment: Check this [Python – Import from parent directory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-parent-directory/)

Comment: There's too much information missing from your post. The python interpreter is usually < 10mb, but what libraries are you importing? Some libraries require a lot of space. What other things is your script doing that might balloon it out? Also, why are you trying to create an exe? Do you need specific version of python and libraries that you cannot install on the target system(s)?

Comment: @Gabe Yep sorry about that, fixed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528763/py2exe-reduce-size-of-the-library-archive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602691/reducing-the-size-of-executable-from-py2exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617868/how-to-reduce-size-of-exe-using-py2exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273039/creating-executable-from-python-script-while-acquiring-small-output-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a virtual environment where you can install your required modules and then create the exe file in that environment itself. The python base library would be there anyway. Check out : [How to include only needed modules in pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312146/how-to-include-only-needed-modules-in-pyinstaller)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pyinstaller` to convert python files to exe.

Installation: `pip install pyinstaller`

Convert (in Terminal): `pyinstaller --onefile "path_to_file.py"`

This would create a "dist" folder in the directory you ran the code in and it would contain the ".exe" file of the python file, this only installs the modules used in the program.

But unfortunately, Size of exe Files are usually big due to the modules used, and cannot be helped (in my opinion)